# DataJpaTest vs SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, lifecycle, applicationcontext

I'm using a @DataJpaTest to test the functionality of my (spring data revision) repositories. All worked fine until I changed functionality in the entities to be saved.
I have callback-methods (@PrePersist and @PreUpdate) which require the currentUser of the change. I determine the user by means of the SecurityContext and as a fallback out of my ConfigurationProperties. The entity is coded as follows.

```java
    @PrePersist
    public void onCreation() {
        final String user = KVLUserProvider.ermittleAngemeldetenUserMitFallback();
        this.erstellungsCcid = user;
        this.veraenderungsCcid = user;

        final LocalDateTime time = ZeitHelper.jetzt();
        this.erstellungsZeitpunkt = time;
        this.veraenderungsZeitpunkt = time;
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onModification() {
        LocalDateTime zpAlt = this.veraenderungsZeitpunkt;
        this.veraenderungsCcid = KVLUserProvider.ermittleAngemeldetenUserMitFallback();
        this.veraenderungsZeitpunkt = ZeitHelper.jetzt();
        logger.trace("onModification {} {} vorher {} nachher {}", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.getId(), zpAlt, veraenderungsZeitpunkt);
    }
```

The KVLUserProvider looks like this.

```java
 private KVLUserProvider(){}

      public static String ermittleAngemeldetenUserMitFallback() {
        String user = Optional
                .of(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null ?
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() : null)
                .orElse(ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext()
                        .getBean(KVLProperties.class).getTechnischerUser());
        logger.debug("Der KVLUserProvider hat folgenden User ermittelt: {}", user);
        return user;
    }
```

The problem occurs in the mentioned class above where i'm trying to obtain die ApplicationContext by means of the ApplicationContextProvider. The Provider implements the ApplicationContextAware Interface, which causes Spring Boot to call the setAppicationConext Method in the implementing class. To be complete here is the ApplicationContextProvider as well.

```java
@Component
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContextProvider instance;

    private ApplicationContextProvider() {
    }

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        if (instance == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("ApplicationContext has not been injected yet!");           
        }
        return instance.applicationContext;
    }

    private static void setProviderInstance(ApplicationContextProvider provider) {
        instance = provider;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext acx) throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = acx;
        setProviderInstance(this);
    }
}
```

The question is what is the missing part of the @DataJpaTest to call the setApplicationContext method like the SpringBootTest does before the PreInitialization phase of the lifecycle? Is there a kind of @Enable... Annotation to achieve this?

The test looks like this.

```java
    @SpringBootTest 
    //@DataJpaTest
    //@AutoConfigureJdbc
    //@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
    @WithMockUser
    @SpringBootTest 

    class Test {
    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ZRepository zRepository;


    @Test
    void testSaveUndUpdateA() {

        Z z = new Z();
        final Z savedZ = zRepository.save(z);
        assertThat(savedZahlungsInformation).isNotNull();

        A a = ABuilder.get(savedZ).build();
        final A savedA = aRepository.save(a);
        assertThat(savedA).isNotNull();

        savedA.setZBetrag(BigDecimal.TEN);
        aRepository.save(auszahlung);

        final Optional<A> actual = Repository.findById(savedA.getId());
        assertThat(actual).isPresent();
        assertThat(actual.get().getId()).isEqualTo(z.getId());
        assertThat(actual.get().getZBetrag()).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.TEN.setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY));
    }
```

The test is green because i changed it to a SpringBootTest. Before my change it was a DataJpaTest and the user was provided in another way.
When i run the test as da DAtaJpaTest it fails because the ApplicationContext is missing.

kind regards.

Comment: another option could be to use [AuditorAware](https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

if the error was "ApplicationContext has not been injected yet!"

try adding on top of the `Test` class

```
@Import({ApplicationContextProvider.class})
```

if after that you get an error for "NoSuchBeanDefinition: No qualifying bean of type '...KVLProperties' available", also add KVLProperties to the annotation

```
@Import({ApplicationContextProvider.class, KVLProperties.class})
```